# Use of templates to raise the level of abstraction of code?

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines

I'm going throught [T.1](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#t1-use-templates-to-raise-the-level-of-abstraction-of-code) of the CppCoreGuidelines, and there are the following examples

Example 1

```
template<typename T>
    // requires Incrementable<T>
T sum1(vector<T>& v, T s)
{
    for (auto x : v) s += x;
    return s;
}
```

Example 2

```
template<typename T>
    // requires Simple_number<T>
T sum2(vector<T>& v, T s)
{
    for (auto x : v) s = s + x;
    return s;
}
```

As per the Guideline above the examples are bad conceptually, as it missed an opportunity for a generalization (constrained to low-level concepts of “can be incremented” or “can be added”).

How can I express the above templates in order to be termed as good generalized template?

Comment: Why not use `s = std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), s)`?    Works with any standard container (and vanilla C-style arrays), does not rely on `s` and elements of `v` being the same type (although adding them needs to be defined).   I'd suggest it is much more general than either of your examples - and `std::accumulate()` can be used for other things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bad thing is in the (commented) concept. which are too specific and linked to implementation as they state that `Incrementable<T>` only restrict to operator `+=` and `Simple_number<T>` only for `+` and `=`.

They provide a correct concept of *"Arithmetic"* which provides a more complete set of operation `+`, `+=`, `=`, ...

So you can substitute one implementation by the other.

Even better would be to replace `vector<T>` by a "`range_view<T>`".

It is not the implementation which is concerned here, but the **concept**.

Some algorithms from STL rely on existence of `operator ==` but doesn't require `operator !=`, or requires the existence of `operator <` but not `operator >`, which make them not generic enough.

Concept of `Orderable<T>` is more generic than `HaveLess<T>`.

Most algorithm rely on some requirement of the type, but should it have the logical conterpart

Comment: so which one would be preferred += or + and = for template ..or it doesn't make in difference ?

Answer (score 0):

The standard library has a good implementation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

It has two versions, one which takes a binary functor so you can sum things without `operator+`.

It takes iterators, so you can sum any iterable container, not just vectors.

It allows the result type to differ from the container's value type.  For example you might want the sum of a `vector<float>` to be stored in a `double` for increased precision.

It also will never copy the values, which is more than can be said for the range-based `for(auto)` loop in the question.

Comment: If you follow the link given by OP, it is not that part which is criticized, but the concept.

Comment: I was just confused with text what other way we can represent sum apart from += and + , =